Outlook addinn Mailitem.forward more then one recipient returns exception
I'm trying to forward a mail. It works ok when there is only 1 recipient. But if I add more then one recipients, I got an exception that "One or more names are not recognized". I checked  smtp addresses , everything is Ok. Then I send a new mail (not a forwarding), these addresses work without any exceptions.
var newItem = mailItem.Forward();    
newItem.Recipients.Add("XXX@domen1.com;YYY@domen1.com");  
newItem.Send(); 

I tryed to use ";" or "," as a separator. There is no difference.

newItem.Recipients.Add("XXX@domen1.com;YYY@domen1.com");   <-- Are you saying this statement gives you an error - or this statement does not give you an error?

it gives me error. The fist address is recognized, the second one is not. I tried many addresses and many combinations.

You need to call newItem.Recipients.Add for each recipient:
newItem.Recipients.Add("XXX@domen1.com"); 
newItem.Recipients.Add("YYY@domen1.com"); 

